# Python speed up function to allocate time dependent elements

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following problem: The code below is relatively slow and I bet there is a faster way to do the appropriate work.

I have two panda time series. dataY is at daily frequency, dataX is at monthly frequency. They overlap in time. I want to create a matrix newX which has len(dataY) rows and lags columns, where lags is the number of monthly observations from dataX back in time. Thus, for each day in dataY, I want to have a row in newX with the past lags observations to that day.

Below my function and an example to run the function.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def get_X(dataY, dataX, freq, lags):
    # provide dataY and dataX with datetime index

    # monthly data
    if freq == 'm':
        firstday = dataY.index[0]
        firstmonth = dataX.index[0]
        # which Series starts first
        if firstday < firstmonth:
            startingday = firstmonth + pd.DateOffset(months=lags)
        else:
            startingday = firstday + pd.DateOffset(months=lags)

        # initialize adjusted Series
        newY = dataY[startingday:]
        newX = np.zeros((len(newY),lags))
        for i in range(len(newY)):
            iday = newY.index[i]
            # allocate the laged values of dataX per timestamp in dataY
            for l in range(0,lags):
                newX[i,l] = np.array(dataX[(iday + pd.DateOffset(months=-l)).strftime('%Y-%m')])[0]
        newX = pd.DataFrame(newX, index = newY.index)
    return [newX, newY]
```

```
nobs = 500
dataY = pd.DataFrame(range(0,nobs), index=pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=nobs))
indexX = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2016', end=dataY.index[len(dataY)-1], freq='M') + pd.DateOffset(days=1)
dataX = pd.DataFrame(range(0,len(indexX)), index=indexX)

%timeit -r5 get_X(dataY, dataX, freq='m', lags=12)
```

This example leads to the following outcome

> 1.42 s ± 113 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1 loop each)

The actually setup however, includes nobs = 5000 and lags = 24, which is even slower.

> 1min 30s ± 2.25 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 5 runs, 1 loop each)

I highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi.  I hope this doesn't come across as negative, but I would initially recommend upgrading the machine you're using. On mine, running the first example was `472 ms ± 1.13 ms per loop` and the second was `29.5 s ± 185 ms per loop` without modifying any of the code.

Comment: So you machine is 3 times faster than mine ;-) Anyhow, since I have to run the function a hundred times, it would take more than half an hour even with yours...

Comment: haha, I guess.  I'm using a different build of numpy, though, with a non-standard BLAS library. I know that there's also one with Intel's MKL library floating around somewhere.